# How to set selected based on a condition in angular 10

Tags: angular, selected

I need to set selected based on a condition.
I am using the following code

```
<option *ngFor="let terms of paymentterms_list" [value]="terms.name" [selected]="terms.default==1?'true':'false'">{{terms.name}}
                                </option>
```

Selected should be set if default is true . But only the last value is selected. I dont want to set using ngmodel. How to fix this

Comment: are you set multiple=true in `select` ?

Comment: no multiple is not set

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Just put your condition in a method.

**HTML**

```
<option *ngFor="let terms of paymentterms_list" 
  [value]="terms.name"
  [selected]="isSelected(terms)">{{terms.name}}
</option>
```

**TypeScript**

```
isSelected(terms: any): boolean { 
   return terms.default === 1;
}
```

Comment: Please, be a little more precise. Does an error appear or does the dscribed behavior not change?

Answer (score 0):

Set key `default_check` or any other instead of `default`
Here is link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-37swtz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

`html code`

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let terms of paymentterms_list" [value]="terms.name" [selected]="terms.default_check==1?true:false">{{terms.name}}
                                </option>
</select>
```

`ts code`

```
paymentterms_list = [
    {
      name: "Abc1",
      default_check: 0
    },
    {
      name: "Abc2",
      default_check: 0
    },
    {
      name: "Abc3",
      default_check: 0
    },
    {
      name: "Abc4",
      default_check: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Abc5",
      default_check: 0
    },
    {
      name: "Abc6",
      default_check: 0
    },
    {
      name: "Abc7",
      default_check: 0
    }
  ];
```